# how to change the administraror in a Developer Edeition account?

Tags: administration, developer-edition

We have a Developer's Edition account with 2 active users: me and the old administrator. I can not find any way to change the "system administrator" profile. I cant change mine. I cant change his (the old one). I dont want to disable my account & then change the name, email, title, photo, etc, history of his account in order to use his account going forward. There must be a way.

I did speak with someone in standard support & they did not immediately know how to do this, so I let him go & said I'd do more investigating.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can just disable the old admin's account if you want to. Otherwise, if you really want to swap places, set the old admin's email to your own, confirm the email, then reset the password, log in as the old admin, and disable your own account.